# calculate Inverse Matrix to a float[,] Array

Tags: c#, math

how can i calculate the inverse Matrix to a Matrix of the type float[,] in C# and in the most efficient way ? 
i've found that a Matrix type in C# can be Inversed i don't know if this help ! 
thank you :)

Comment: You might use a search engine of your choice and find possible algorithms. If you encounter any problems in the implementation feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Which one of the Matrix types? The one that comes with WPF? And about your float array - is the matrix size limitied? Is its size known?

Comment: @ Alex:  yeah the size is known

Comment: @ Howard : i know an appropriate algo ! , but i think an algo like this must be found in .net library , it is needed every where

Comment: How about you post either an example matrix, or at least describe its structure and form (aprox. size, where are the zeros, is it symmetric, etc). Then maybe we can recommend a more targeted approach.

Answer (score 1):

General linear algebra algorithms (arbitrary size matrices/vectors) are not found anywhere in the .NET framework. But there are surely countless 3rd party frameworks that provide this.

Do you really need to invert a matrix? Often you might think you need the inverse, for example when solving a linear system Ax=b, but in fact you do not need to explicitly calculate the inverse of A, but rather do a decomposition of A to solve the linear system more efficiently.

Comment: QR works for overconstrained systems, but is not that well suited to square matrices as LU is.

Comment: In addition, `Cholesky` decomposition works best for symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 1):

These are general math libraries (.NET or not) that tell you, or have functions to invert matrices. If the form is for `double` you might need to convert back and forth. I have used (3) below to write a LU decomposition for a general matrix that works very well. In general, for dense (not many zeros) matrix, the most efficient way is [`Gauss-Seidel`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) or [`LU`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition).

1. http://www.mathdotnet.com/
2. https://github.com/lutzroeder/mapack
3. http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html